# Specifying an in-class using-declaration targeting different functions with the same name

Tags: c++, syntax, using-declaration

When using a using-declaration to expose base class' methods, how can I go about exposing methods with the same name but different parameters?

```
class Base
{
protected:
    void f();
    void f(int);
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    using Base::f; // which is exposed, and how can I manually specify?
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way, all method in the base class will be exposed and if you want to use just a specific method in derived class you need to use `forwarding function`

```
class Base{
  protected:
  void f();
  void f(int);
};

class Derived: public Base
{
 public:
  void f()    //forwarding function
  {
    Base::f();
  }
};
```

for more explanation of this method you can read Scott Meyers's first book, an Item dedicated to Avoid‬‬ ‫‪hiding‬‬ ‫‪inherited‬‬ ‫‪names‬‬([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=U7lTySXdFk0C&pg=PT184&lpg=PT184&dq=%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAAvoid%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAhiding%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAinherited%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAnames%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20scott%20meyer&source=bl&ots=nP7Sray7k9&sig=ACfU3U36I-WAr0WYkCmJh2RCddpoxtB49Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP-6OFx-HkAhXjdd8KHUPPBA8Q6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAAvoid%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAhiding%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAinherited%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20%E2%80%AB%E2%80%AAnames%E2%80%AC%E2%80%AC%20scott%20meyer&f=false) to this item)

Comment: This seems like a very hacky solution, though I guess the feeling is very common with the C++ language. Would you know if this actually causes a seperate function to be emitted? Does it cost any more than if I were to otherwise just specify another name for the base-class method?

Comment: @invertedPanda, the function will be implicitly inlined, so this will cause no any more cost on your program I guess